# Apache throwing "Internal Server Error" when using mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I am setting up reverse proxy using the below code and the URL [https://192.168.241.104/] throws error. I am able to access the URL otherwise if i remove the proxy.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    # backend server and forwarded path
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    ProxyPass / https://192.168.241.104/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.241.138/
</IfModule>
```

EDIT: The SSL logs suggest the below error:

```
[Thu Apr 06 06:09:14.185743 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 7497] [client 192.168.241.1:51844] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /index.html
[Thu Apr 06 06:09:14.185754 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 7497] [client 192.168.241.1:51844] AH01097: pass request body failed to 192.168.241.104:443 (192.168.241.104) from 192.168.241.1 ()
[Thu Apr 06 06:09:19.232273 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 7500] (502)Unknown error 502: [client 192.168.241.1:51851] AH01084: pass request body failed to 192.168.241.104:443 (192.168.241.104)
[Thu Apr 06 06:09:19.232434 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 7500] [client 192.168.241.1:51851] AH00898: Error during SSL Handshake with remote server returned by /
[Thu Apr 06 06:09:19.232443 2017] [proxy_http:error] [pid 7500] [client 192.168.241.1:51851] AH01097: pass request body failed to 192.168.241.104:443 (192.168.241.104) from 192.168.241.1 ()
[Thu Apr 06 06:09:23.855447 2017] [proxy:error] [pid 7496] (502)Unknown error 502: [client 192.168.241.1:51855] AH01084: pass request body failed to 192.168.241.104:443 (192.168.241.104), referer: https://192.168.241.104/
```

Comment: Try `openssl s_client -connect 192.168.241.104:443` and let us know what you see, also set `LogLevel proxy:trace3` for a more detailed output on why mod_proxy is failing to contact the backend.

Comment: @ezra-s Sorry for replying late, got busy at work. Here is the output:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxF9oSekI_PwSDBtbHBhRDV1TG8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Still nothing too obvious, everything seems "fine". Which version of openssl is the apache server using? You can check that by looking at the server error.log start messages.

Comment: @ezra-s Here you go

openssl-libs-1.0.1e-60.el7_3.1.x86_64
openssl-1.0.1e-60.el7_3.1.x86_64